# How to fix matplotlib's Radio Button's single-press delay

Tags: python, user-interface, matplotlib, delay

I have a line plot in matplotlib, and I have a radio button widget next to it to select the data being shown to the user, either the data at a selected point, or the average.  However, when an unselected radio button is pressed, nothing happens; only when another radio button is pressed (it doesn't matter which one), the value then changes to the initial selection.  This one-press delay continues in any combination of radio button presses.

Here is the relevant code:

```
def update_radio(val):
    if val == 'avg':
        myplot.set_data(xlist, avg_ys)
    elif val == 'select':
        myplot.set_data(xlist, select_ys)
radios.on_clicked(update_radio)
```

How can I fix this delay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to provide more details. A minimal reproducible code at least.

In the mean time, did you try adding a `plt.draw()` in your function?

```
def update_radio(val):
    if val == 'avg':
        myplot.set_data(xlist, avg_ys)
    elif val == 'select':
        myplot.set_data(xlist, select_ys)
    plt.draw()
radios.on_clicked(update_radio)
```

Comment: plt.draw() was the missing line.